# Writing Positive and Negative Intervals

Tags: linear-algebra

I was discussing writing a negative interval for the following graph with some colleagues and was told that when writing intervals I must always use parentheses. In this case, I feel the interval upon which the function is negative is represented by [-10, 2). My colleague corrected me and said it should be (-10, 2). Who is correct and why?[image]

Comment: $x=-10$ seems to be included by the filling-in of the dot, so I would agree with $[-10,2)$

Comment: In contrast—the interval on which the graph is positive would be $(2,3)$, since the dot at $x=3$ is not filled in.

Comment: @Henry, that was my reasoning as well. But my colleague replied and stated that all intervals must be written with parentheses and that their degree in mathematics was superior so they were therefore correct. They have a masters and I have a bachelors. Not that it should matter, but it was enough for me to reach out to this community.

Comment: I suspect a miscommunication: they may be using "parentheses" to mean any of `( [ {` and merely reminding that set notation opens and closes with them, rather than insisting that intervals are always to be specified with parentheses `( )`.

Comment: They were specific that they meant an open interval not including -10. I suggested they were meaning for increasing and decreasing, as endpoints may not be seen as increasing or decreasing, but they reiterated that intervals like this are always open. It just doesn’t seem appropriate to me to use for the case of this graph, though. If I’m wrong, I’d like to understand why.

Comment: if $f$ is a continuous function, the $f^{-1}((-\infty, 0))$ will be an open set in its domain. If the domain of this function were all of $\Bbb R$, then yes, the answer would be an open interval. But the domain of this function is $[-10,3)$ and $[-10,2)$ is an open subset of that domain, even though it is not open in $\Bbb R$. You have had at least one, and very likely three, PHDs agree with you, so you need not fear from bogus arguments from authority (and *all* arguments strictly from authority are bogus).

Comment: I appreciate the responses! Thank you for the help!